# How the template deduction for functions work in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have come across this piece of code that is made for an Event Dispatcher. it will first check to see if the type of event is the one it wants then it will run a templated function with the event as its argument, I have a problem with the syntax of the argument for that function ( What does the  (*(T*)&m_Event) mean, why an asterisk before T? why one after T?)

```
class EventDispatcher
    {
        template<typename T>
        using EventFn = std::function<bool(T&)>;
    public:
        EventDispatcher(Event& event)
            : m_Event(event)
        {
        }

        template<typename T>
        bool Dispatch(EventFn<T> func)
        {
            if (m_Event.GetEventType() == T::GetStaticType())
            {
                m_Event.m_Handled = func(*(T*)&m_Event);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    private:
        Event& m_Event;
    };
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "template deduction" exactly you're asking about. If you're wondering about template argument deducion for a call to `Dispatch<T>` then you'll have to show us how `Dispatch` is called…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(T*)` is a C-style cast that is used here to cast `&m_Event` to a pointer to a `T`. The result of all of that is then dereferenced (the leftmost `*`). In the end, this is just a suspiciously complicated way of passing a reference to the object `m_Event` to the call to `func` (unless there's some operator overloading going on that we should be aware of).

Generally, this code doesn't look great to me. The fact that a cast like that would be needed here is concerning. Chances are this whole contraption is actually invoking undefined behavior, but it's hard to say without knowing what, e.g., the whole `GetEventType()` and `GetStaticType()` business is about and what all the types involved here actually are…

PS: the parameter `func` would probably better be passed by reference here.

Comment: yeah, I don't like it either. but it did help me a lot, so thank you very much

Comment: @WiderGamer As I said, chances are it's not just ugly but actually incorrect. But can't say for sure without knowing what `T` is and what the `GetType()` stuff does exactly…

Comment: Equivalent cpp style cast `m_Event.m_Handled = func(static_cast<T&>(m_Event));`